# How do I detect/handle a browser's failure to play a media file

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, media-player, soundmanager2

I'm using a JavaScript [library](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) to play mp3 files. Due to circumstances out of my control, I periodically link to a file that cannot be played. When this happens, I see a message in Firebug explaining that the file could not be decoded.

> Media resource https://example.com/bad_file.mp3 could not be decoded.

[image: screen capture of firebug message concerning bad file]
[Click here to see the behavior in action on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thompcha/4ptg7jra/)

Since there is nothing I can do to replace the files, I'm looking for a way of determining whether or not a file can be played. The framework provides an `onerror()` method for when the script itself fails to load, but nothing for when the file can't be played.

While an answer specific to SoundManager2 would be acceptable, I would prefer a solution that is independent of any particular library or framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can add an onerror event listener to elements that load resources. So for instance since you are doing audio you would attach an event listener to the audio element

```
//assume this html:
//<audio id="myaudio" src="http://badurl.com/mp3.mp3"></audio>
document.getElementById("myaudio").addEventListener("error",function(event){
  //do error handling here
});
```

For SoundManager2 specifically you can pass in a onload callback option, it will be passed a `success` variable, true for it loaded false if not, [API reference](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-onload)

```
var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
  id: 'aSound',
  url: 'http://badurl.com/mp3.mp3',
  onload:function(success){
     if(!success){
        //error happened
     }
  } 
});
mySound.play();
```

Comment: The second solution only works if I create the sound programmatically. If I'm relying on SoundManager2 to find my mp3 links and create players for them, I don't have access to their parameters.

Comment: @Keyslinger, Then change the [defaultOptions](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smdefaults) to use an onload event: `soundManager.defaultOptions.onload = function(){}`

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the standard `<audio src="whatever.mp3">` notation you could use this script to hook into any audio errors that occur:

```
function handleSourceError(e) { alert('Error loading: '+e.target.src) }
function handleMediaError(e) {
  switch (e.target.error.code) {
    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED:
      alert('You aborted the media playback.'); break;
    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK:
      alert('A network error caused the media download to fail.'); break;
    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE:
      alert('The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.'); break;
    case e.target.error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED:
      alert('The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.'); break;
    default:
      alert('An unknown media error occurred.');
  }
}

var toArray = Array.prototype.slice;
toArray.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')).forEach(function(audio){
  audio.addEventListener('error', handleMediaError);
  toArray.apply(audio.getElementsByTagName('source')).forEach(function(source){
    source.addEventListener('error', handleSourceError);
  });
});
```

If you could get a reference to an `Audio` instance then you could add the error handler as such:

```
audioInstance.addEventListener('error', handleMediaError)
```